# Reset DNS Cache on Mac

Tags: macos, dns, reset

I recently switched hosting services for my domain, and as I've been checking up on it recently, I've noticed that the changes have finished propagating, but my laptop (Mac OS X Mountain Lion, if that helps) still navigates to the old server when I type in the URL.

If I navigate to the page on any other device, it takes me to the new server. How can I reset my laptop's DNS cache? It happens in every browser, as well as displaying the old IP when I ping the domain from Terminal.

Could this have anything to do with my Wi-fi? My other devices are connected to the same network and are not experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`dscacheutil -flushcache` is what you are looking for.  There is a [manual page on developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dscacheutil.1.html) that describes its usage.

I think that [sending a hangup to mDNSResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mDNSResponder.8.html) is the *new* solution to flushing the cache though - `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` should do the trick.

**Note** This probably should have been asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Lets all thank Apple for killing those valuable developer links. Here is a third party link : https://ss64.com/mac/dscacheutil.html

Answer (score 0):

You can save a .scpt file to your desktop for quicker access and simplicity.
open the "Script Editor", add the following command and save to your desktop:
Copy and paste the following line including quotes:

do shell script "sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder; say cache flush completed successfully" with administrator privileges

Then simply double-click the file overtime you need to flush :)
This works on El Capitan 10.11.x
Hope this helps!

[screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkgL.png)